# Use JWT when using callout to post data from Salesforce to third party API

Tags: jwt, salesforce, apex

I have a requirement where on lead conversion in Salesforce, I need to call a third party API and post converted lead's details to that API. I have covered up til the part where we need to add endpoint of the API in Remote site settings in Salesforce and callout is made successfully. Now comes the tricky party - I had made the sample using a public API but now for development purposes, I need to call my API and use JWT token for authentication and security. I looked out for this but I am all confused because most of the samples/content correspond to third party applications consuming Salesforce API and using JWT instead of consumer secret and id which isn't quite what I am looking for.
I need to call a third party API from Salesforce and that API would need a JWT token from Salesforce for authentication. How can this be achieved? I am new to Salesforce and find some concepts confusing so have come to this platform for seeking correct information.